# Redirecting to a different controller method - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm currently revamping my application. I have a method called "Test" in my controller which is being currently being called my many pages. I've now created a new method called "TestNew" in my controller and I want few of my pages to be redirected to the new method.

It would be great if you can let me know of a quick fix that can be done at one place so that by putting some condition like

```
if(viewName = "abc")
```

then redirect to "TestNew", instead of making change across the application. I've tried doing something in

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
```

but this never gets called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried RedirectToAction() method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This should be really simple as per all ASP MVC books & basics:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   return RedirectToAction("NewTest");
}
```

Hope this helps